# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Object Names

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi, visualstudiocode

I need to extract data from Salesforce Marketing Cloud. I'm using KingswaySoft SSIS Integration Toolkit to do the ETL, but I don't know the tables that retrieve the columns I need. I've searched on the documentation, but I wasn't able to identify the proper columns.

This is how my connection manager to the source SF Marketing Cloud looks like:
[image: SF Marketing Cloud Connection Manager]

KingswaySoft SSIS Integration Toolkit - Salesforce Marketing Cloud Source Editor:

[image: KingswaySoft SSIS Integration Toolkit - Salesforce Marketing Cloud Source Editor]

These are the columns I need:

- Journey Name
- Journey Activity Name
- Email Sends
- Email Delivery Rate
- Email Bounce Rate
- Email Open Rate
- Email Click To Open Rate
- Email Unique Opens
- Email Click Rate
- Email Unique Clicks
- Email Unsubscribe Rate
- Email Unique Unsubscribes
- Subscriber_Key
- timestamp
- Birthdate
- CouponCode
- ExitDate
- IsRedeemed
- ClaimedDate
- ExpirationDate
- EngagementPhase
- SentEngagement1
- SentEngagement2
- SentEngagement3
- SentEngagement4
- OpenedEngagement1
- OpenedEngagement2
- OpenedEngagement3
- OpenedEngagement4
- ClickedEngagement1
- ClickedEngagement2
- ClickedEngagement3
- ClickedEngagement4

To extract from Salesforce Service Cloud, I've used a Chrome extension "Salesforce Inspector" where I could search the column name and would obtain the source table, but it doesn't seem to work for SF marketing cloud.

Answer (score 1):

The system tables in Marketing Cloud are called Data views, they hold some information that you have listed, so eg. “Journey Activity Name” from your list might refer to the `_JourneyActivity` table.

This diagram shows all available Data Views along with column names:

[image]

Please refer to this [article](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/) and [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) for details such as data types etc.

Some additional information can also be pulled using Tracking Extracts in Automation Studio and stored on an FTP, but not sure if this is what you are using:

> Tracking extracts provide granular tracking data for import from Email
> Studio into external systems. Use tracking extracts to export granular
> data regarding several different aspects of email send jobs, such as
> clicks, bounces, and survey data, from Marketing Cloud. Then, import
> that information into an automation or system.

For details see here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_as_tracking_extract.htm&language=en_US

It’s also possible that your integration uses SOAP objects, which are listed here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/soap_web_service_objects.html

It seems, that some of the tables you have listed are custom tables (called Data Extensions) - for those, you will need to log into Marketing Cloud to get their names and details, as they are specific to your account.

Comment: I'm using KingswaySoft SSIS Integration Toolkit - Salesforce Marketing Cloud Source Editor to extract the data, but I don't seem to be able to access the DataViews that you mention.

Comment: I've added a print of some of the tables I can access, using this dataflow component from KingswaySoft SSIS Integration Toolkit - Salesforce Marketing Cloud Source Editor

Comment: They might be SOAP objects, I’ve added a link to my answer

Comment: yes it seems that my integration uses SOAP objects, but I don't seem to find the tables I need on those SOAP objects. Can you give me the SOAP table that contains some of the columns I need to extract?

Comment: The link I provided lists all the SOAP objects available and their properties, there aren’t any other and there are no SOAP tables - if you’re sure that there are some tables out there that have the data you need, please reach out to someone that has access to your Marketing Cloud instance and ask them to give you a list of all Data Extension in the account

Comment: It seems that these SOAP objects have the information that I need:
Journey,
JourneyActivity,
Send,
and Subscriber
But I could only find Send and Subscriber. The other two objects are not being detected because these are probably custom objects.

Comment: Journey-related stuff is not accessible via SOAP API, it can only be accessed via REST API but I don’t think that’s what you’re looking for: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/routes.html?q=get%20campaign

Comment: I've added one more screenshot of the connection manager in SSIS (Visual Studio) to the source SF Marketing Cloud and in fact the connection service url is mentions SOAP. Any idea on how to extract those objects Journey and JourneyActivity, to obtain the columns that I need?

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/lesleyhiggins/sfmc-data-views/blob/master/Journey and https://github.com/lesleyhiggins/sfmc-data-views/blob/master/Journey%20Activity

Comment: Above links show how to access the Journey and Journey Activity data views using SOAP API. You’d have to implement it in your ETL tool.

Comment: but how can I implement it using the Kingswaysoft SSIS Integration Toolkit connectors?

https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-salesforce/help-manual/salesforce-marketing-cloud

Comment: This is a question for a Kingswaysoft forum I am afraid, not for a Marketing Cloud forum

Comment: do you know if there's any? I couldn't find the link to kingswaysoft forum

Comment: No, never heard of Kingswaysoft before